# Can a UIWebView web form be populated programmatically?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

If you have a UIWebView, and load a web page with a form on it, can you programmatically populate that form? Either with objective-c or javascript, or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code sample:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.myForm.myText.value='text from Obj-C';"];
```

You can, basically, execute any JavaScript on your web view...

Answer (score 2):

You can execute javascript with the [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) method on the UIWebView. This will let you use `document.getElementById()` etc. to locate and manipulate elements on the page.

Comment: Sure, I had a vague idea that was possible, but do you know how to fill in form elements with JS? In my case, it's just a few plain text fields.